# Android Exception in WebSocket SendTextMessage

Tags: android

I am facing a problem with sendTextMessage in Websocket. I am trying to send a message to server after connecting to it, but still i am getting a NUllPointerException.

I am including necessary code here:

```
    final WebSocketConnection mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();
    new WebSocketConnectionHandler().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    try {
       Thread.sleep(2000);
    }  catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
   if(mConnection.isConnected()){
      Data joinData=new Data("join",playerId+"");
      try{mConnection.sendTextMessage(gson.toJson(joinData));}
      catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       Log.d("SENTTTTTTT:",gson.toJson(joinData));
    }
    Log.d("here:","after scoket");
```

In WebSocketConnectionHandler i am creating the connection and printing a log message after connecting to the server.

```
      D/connecteddddd﹕ ws://192.168.0.107:8080/spring-websocket-test/game
      W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
      W/System.err﹕ at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection.sendTextMessage(WebSocketConnection.java:137)
      W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tic.WebSocketTic.<init>(WebSocketTic.java:90)
      D/SENTTTTTTT:﹕ {"action":"join","playerId":"0","turn":false}
      D/here:﹕ after scoket
```

I am really not able to understand why i am getting the NullPointerException ever after checking the  `if(mConnection.isConnected())` condition. ( Even  from logs it is clear that connection is established before sending the message).

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with the way i am doing it and what is the correct way to  do it???

**Edit**:

The corresponding `de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection.sendTextMessage` code is:

```
        protected WebSocketWriter mWriter;
        public void sendTextMessage(String payload) {
            mWriter.forward(new WebSocketMessage.TextMessage(payload));
        }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you show the relevant code from de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection

Comment: @MaxMeijer i edited the question to include the corresponding code.

Comment: Are you sure mWriter is initialized before sendTextMessage is called?

Comment: I had the same doubt , that is why i have tried `Thread.sleep(2000)`, I will debug it completely and try to find it out.